# Set computerName using an MSDeploy parameter

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

Our deployment process would make it easier to supply the computerName for a deployment using a parameter file.

I've been reading through the [documentation for `declareParam` and `setParam`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and I've experimented with using kind=DeploymentObjectAttribute, but I'm having trouble determining if this is what it's meant for (it's the only parameter kind that seems like it might be what I need).

For example, instead of this command:

```
msdeploy.exe ... -dest:auto,computerName=PLUTO
```

I would like to use this command:

```
msdeploy.exe ... -dest:auto -setParamFile:C:\Params.xml
```

And have the following Params.xml file:

```
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="ComputerName" value="PLUTO" />
</parameters>
```

Comment: I would like to know this as well